How does a Task understand that it has already been executed if the thread is released?
For example, if I asynchronously contact the database with a request. How should a Task understand that it has already been completed and change its status?
Do I understand correctly that when I access the database asynchronously, essentially no thread is waiting for it or only the calling thread is freed, and behind it there is an additional thread that is waiting for a response from the database?

There is too much to unpack in the question. You might find the async / await and Task posts in this blog useful: https://blog.stephencleary.com/

You could also check out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/task-asynchronous-programming-model

When you initiate an asynchronous database request with async and await, the calling thread is freed to perform other tasks. This ensures that the thread is not blocked waiting for the database response, allowing for more efficient use of system resources.
Contrary to some misconceptions, no additional thread is waiting for the database response. Instead, the request is sent, and the operating system handles the continuation of the method once the response is received. This continuation is picked up by an available thread from the thread pool.
The Task object associated with the asynchronous operation tracks its status, such as RanToCompletion, Faulted, or Canceled. By using the await keyword, the method execution automatically resumes upon task completion, which can include updating the task status or performing follow-up actions.
This model significantly increases efficiency and scalability. It uses threads only when necessary, freeing them up when waiting for I/O operations to complete. This approach allows the system to handle a larger number of concurrent operations more effectively.
